# How to validate a dependency property on a UserControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, mvvm

My view model implements `IDataErrorInfo` and contains a `Message` property that is validated.

I have created a `UserControl` with a `Text` `DependencyProperty` that is bound to `Message`. There are several controls on my `UserControl` that are bound to `Text` (which therefore show `Message`).

How can I show validation errors on the controls in my `UserControl` that are not bound to `Message` directly?

Comment: This can be achieved by making the UserControl implement IDataErrorInfo as well as the view model. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After quite some time, I have managed to figure out a solution that I thought I should share in case others find it useful:

Basically I have added a `PropertyChangedCallback` on my `Text` `DependencyProperty`. In this call-back I get the binding between `Text` and the property on the view model and check it for validation errors. If a `ValidationError` is found, I go through all the controls in my `UserControl` that are bound to `Text`, and give their binding the same error using `Validation.MarkInvalid`.

EDIT:

Copying the validation errors like this works fine if I put the code below in a button click event handler. If however the code is in the `PropertyChangedCallback` for `Text` then nothing happens. Does anyone have a solution?

```
// Get the binding from the Text property to the view model.
BindingExpression textBindingExpression = BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(this,
    MyUserControl.TextProperty);

// If there is a validation error, then give it to the control bindings.
if (textBindingExpression != null && textBindingExpression.ValidationError != null) {

    Validation.MarkInvalid(this.MyTextBox.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty),
        textBindingExpression.ValidationError);

    Validation.MarkInvalid(this.MyTextBlock.GetBindingExpression(TextBlock.TextProperty),
        textBindingExpression.ValidationError);
}
```

Comment: Did you ever figure anything out? I'm having a very similar issue and it is beyond frustrating me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I came up with which allows a `UserControl` with Dependency Properties to "wrap" the validation from the View Model it is bound to.

Firstly I followed the pattern in [this post](https://blog.scottlogic.com/2012/02/06/a-simple-pattern-for-creating-re-useable-usercontrols-in-wpf-silverlight.html) to create the desired `DataContext` hierarchy.

XAML:

```
<!-- Some boilerplate attributes snipped -->
<UserControl x:Class="App.Views.UserControls.MyUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App.Views.UserControls"             
             Validation.ErrorTemplate="{x:Null}">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"
          DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=local:MyUserControl}}">
         <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
   </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

This way, the DataContext of the control is the view model inherited from the parent, which is where the validation is done. This is then overridden on the control's root child  element to be the control itself, which allows binding to the Dependency Properties in code-behind. Also note that the control's `ErrorTemplate` has been nulled out - this is to prevent the default red box appearing.

The inherited view model can now be accessed from the control's code behind quite simply:

```
private INotifyDataErrorInfo ViewModelErrors => DataContext as INotifyDataErrorInfo;
```

Now implement `INotifyDataErrorInfo` in the user control and wrap the view model:

```
public bool HasErrors => ViewModelErrors.HasErrors;

public IEnumerable GetErrors(string propertyName)
{
    return ViewModelErrors.GetErrors(propertyName);
}
```

The tricky part comes when you need to know which model property your control dependency property is bound to. This would be easier if you could look up registered dependency properties by name and interrogate the binding, but I couldn't find a way to do that without reflection. Therefore I used the `PropertyChangedCallback` of the dependency property to manually build a list of mappings. The parameters to the callback contain all the required information.

```
// Maps User Control properties to their View Model properties.
private readonly Dictionary<string, string> _propertyMappings = new Dictionary<string, string>();

// This should work for any property.
private static void OnDependencyPropertyValueChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var userControl = (MyUserControl)d;
    var dependencyPropertyName = e.Property.Name;

    // Create this mapping one time only.
    if (!userControl._propertyMappings.ContainsKey(dependencyPropertyName))
    {
        // Get the binding from the property to the view model.
        var binding = BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(d, e.Property);

        if (binding != null)
        {
            // Create a mapping of user control property to view model property.
            // This will let us look up the error from the view model.
            var boundPropertyName = binding.ResolvedSourcePropertyName;

            userControl._propertyMappings[dependencyPropertyName] = boundPropertyName;
         }
    }
}
```

Then incorporate this in to `GetErrors`:

```
public IEnumerable GetErrors(string propertyName)
{
    if (ViewModelErrors != null && _propertyMappings.ContainsKey(propertyName))
    {
        return ViewModelErrors.GetErrors(_propertyMappings[propertyName]);
    }
    else
    {
        return Enumerable.Empty<string>();
    }
}
```

That should be enough. Validation is done in the model and the results pulled down to the user control. No need to duplicate.